# Grabbing ID by Prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a question regarding grabbing content from an e-mail form before/while it submits.

I am using the code

```
        <script>
            $('#nm_mc_form_id-1352905826').submit(function(e){
                // Grab the email address from the form
                var email = $('#EMAIL-1352905826').val();
            });
        </script>
```

As you can see the from id and the email id are dynamic.  Is there any way to grab the ID's based on their prefix?

I did see in another SO (yes I have looked around ;)) something along the lines of:

```
$('#id').find('p')
```

Just not sure how that works or if it's what I need?

I am one of those guys who likes to learn so please provide a little insight as to what your recommendation is.

Cheers!

Comment: Use `data-*` attributes for tying real data to the DOM, not IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wild card `^ is used for element starting with given string`.

```
$('[id^=nm_mc_form_id-]').submit(function(e){
            // Grab the email address from the form
            var email = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Amazing, one question, how will this know to grab the e-mail field of that form though?  Should I be using [id^=EMAIL-]? - Really appreciate the help

Comment: Yes, you should be using [id^=EMAIL-] because $(this) in this case would be the entire form.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an attribute selector -

```
var email = $('[id^="EMAIL-"]').val();
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, looks like you answered my comment above, my thoughts exactly - you are all awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attribute starts with ^` or `attribute contains selector *`

```
$('[id^="nm_mc_form_id-"]')  // Starts with

$('[id*="nm_mc_form_id-"]')  // contains
```

Comment: Sushanth thank you for the response, that's really helpful to know for future programming as well!